# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "153 asd 654";
    int count = 0;
    char c1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        c1 = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c1)) {
            int temp = i;
            while (Character.isDigit(c1)) {
                temp++;
                count++;
                c1 = s.charAt(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

выкидывает ошибку StringIndexOutOfBoundsException,если в строке дописать любую букву ошибка уходит,может кто-нибудь объяснить почему так происходит?Условие задачи такое:нужно посчитать кол-во чисел в строке

---

всем огромное  спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу:)

Comment: Если в конце строки добавить любую букву,то ошибка уходит и переменная temp не уходит в бесконечность,у нее максимальная граница s.length(),я думаю что проблема именно в этом,но не уверен

Comment: Нет. Ещё как уходит. Банально сделайте внутри цикла `System.out.println(temp);` а строку `c1 = s.charAt(temp);` закомментируйте и увидите.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в while цикле не проверяете длину строки. Отсюда и ошибка.

Код подсчета цифр должен быть таким

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "153 asd 654";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c1 = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c1)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: я дико извиняюсь за свою ошибку,первый раз за долгое время пишу вопрос.Не указал условие к задаче,нужно посчитать количество чисел в строке,не цифр,а именно чисел

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (Character.isDigit(c1)) {
        temp++;
        count++;
        c1 = s.charAt(temp);
    }
```

Вот здесь есть ошибка, **temp** - увеличивается "+" бесконечности, вывод такой, что **c1 = s.charAt(temp)** когда это строка начинает работать кидает **"StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"**, из-за того что у тебя длина строки равно 10, а **temp++** увеличивается и индекс становится **10**, как ты наверняка знаешь что индексы начинают считать с 0, поэтому нету 10 индекса вот поэтому выдает ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Если не понятно написал то прощу прощение, я просто я не русский поэтому могу что-то не правильно написать, прошу прощение еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите на `charAt`. Символа по нужному индексу нет. Скорее всего в этом месте: `s.charAt(temp)`, потому что `temp` у вас накручивается в плюс бесконечность))